# How would you print something in a box created in QT Designer through python?

Tags: python, qt, printing

I am trying to create a "save date" button that will simply save the selected date. [This is what the program looks like so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3ha6.png). When the user clicks save date, the date is printed, however it is done through the python console. I would like for it to print within the little box right beside the button, however I am not sure how to set it to print in that specific place.

```
def PrintDate(self):
    print(self.dateEdit.text())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Ui_Form()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Holy dang. Can you please remove the unnecessary code from your question?

Comment: LOL not all the code, I meant remove the code that is not related to the save button.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like all you need it to declare a variable that gets the value of `self.dateEdit.text()`
and then make another text label with that value.

EDIT:
Declaring a variable isn't actually necessary: You could just enter `self.dateEdit.text()` into the text label. (provided the text label is set AFTER dateEdit is declared.)

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll get to it.

Comment: Hello again. It appears I'm still having a problem. The first time the program loads up, the date appears in the box, however, clicking save date again will print the date in the python window instead of updating or adding another date to the box. What could I do?